# Why are windows definitions missing on msvc++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-services, undefined

I have not been coding in MSVC lately. I have been assigned an old code that has lots of errors but most of the missing definitions are of Windows API.

For example, `LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX` is not defined and is causing C2061 compile error. But I already included `Winsvc.h` or `Windows.`h. I know that this is just a definition, I checked my C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\ for the definition can be found on the `Winsvc.h`. So I added the SDK on the directory list (Tools > Options > Directory Tab).

I also downloaded the Windows SDK February 2003 update which is the last version that works with msvc6. ([ref](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/83205c43-ef46-447d-ae54-92bbeb543c38))

Just for completeness, My PC is Windows XP SP3. Microsoft Visual C++ Enterprise Edition with SP6 installed. I also installed the Windows SDK February 2003 update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you're including `WinSvc.h` before `LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX` is being used?  I would suggest examining the output from the preprocessor (`cl.exe /E file.c > output`).

Comment: @jamesdlin. WinSvc.h was included on top of the header before the LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX definition was used.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to answer. It works for me. What is `WINVER` defined to be?

Comment: Are you perhaps using a precompiled header?  And again, look at the preprocessed output and verify that `LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX` is declared before it's being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by fixing the order of the include directory via Tools > Options > Directory Tab.

Before the VC98 folder was on top of the SDK.
1st C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\INCLUDE
2nd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\INCLUDE
3rd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE
4th C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\include

Just place the SDK directory to the top of the list and it works.

The suggestion to use /E option by [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) was helpful. Also I set the /E option in the Project Settings > Library Tab > Project Option textbox. The log would be placed in the .plg file inside the project folder.

This would also apply to missing lib file. Set the directory to the SDK directory for library.